# A question about log messages

Tags: errors

In order to suppress messages such that

```
File: 2446.eps Graphic file (type eps)
      <2446.eps>
File: 2448.eps Graphic file (type eps)
      <2448.eps>
```

from the log file, i use the command

```
\def\@providesfile#1[#2]{\@addtofilelist{ #2}\endgroup}
```

and these messages are dissapeared ... The strange thing is that now the log file contains messages that not existed before, such that

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 1102) in paragraph at lines 696--698
\LGR/txr/m/n/10 fa-ko'u (akt'ina 1) kai sth sun'eqeia a-
```

If I comment out the command

```
\def\@providesfile#1[#2]{\@addtofilelist{ #2}\endgroup}
```

these messages are not displayed again. In order to fix the errors associated with those messages i correct accordingly the appropriate parameters (in almost all cases these messages are associated with the wrapfigure command) .. why this is happen and what i have to do? the simple solution is to comment out the above command but i think that i just hide the problem without actually solving it.

Comment: Any way you can provide something to replicate this behaviour on our end? Note that `\@providesfile` has two different definitions. It may be better to use `\AtBeginDocument{\def\@providesfile...}`.

Comment: i will try to create a MWE and i will add it in the question .. the problem concerns lines associated with minipage and wrapfig ,, the above mentioned command is used before document class .. i will try your suggestion

Comment: Who told you to redefine `\@providesfile` in that way?  You are picking up (and trying to adapt) the version of that command that is used in `ltdirchk.dtx`, *not* the “true” one…!  **Edit:** And, above all, why do you ever want to suppress log messages about the files being loaded?!?

Comment: I found the solution in the net and it worked .. i load 1800+ eps figures in the book i translate and i want to suppress these messages to speed up the compilation ... if this definition is erroneous and causes the error i can simply forget it and let the related info stored in the log (in this case the messages are not displayed) .. the fact is that in the MWE i constructed this strange behavior does not appear .. maybe the solution is to forget about \@providesfile command, since in this case all are ok

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cutting out the logging makes the log a lot smaller but doesn't make so much difference on run times, I get the following on a file with 2000 images.

no logging

```
real    0m23.821s
user    0m2.718s
sys     0m20.718s
```

(log size 9072)

by default

```
real    0m23.917s
user    0m3.062s
sys     0m20.609s
```

(log size 498986)

```
\documentclass{article}



\newcount\zz
\def\wlog#1{}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\GenericInfo}[2]{}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}


\loop
\ifnum\zz<2000
\includegraphics{example-image}

\advance\zz 1
\repeat


\end{document}
```

Although if you want to try, then

```
\def\wlog#1{}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\GenericInfo}[2]{}
```

is what you need (before loading the `graphics` package)

Comment: have you tried using Emacs/AUCTeX. I get the impression voluminous logs also induce significant slowdown when the job is launched from Emacs/AUCTeX.

Comment: well I have used emacs almost every day since about 1987 so yes (although most of my tex files are small examples off this site, and I more often run tex from an xterm by hand than via auctex's subshell) @jfbu